# cannot update shopping cart error: After add cutom comment bar in cart

Tags: cart, error, upgrade, shopping

i am facing this issue. while update comment in cart page. and same is working on different source,pl help me to solve this issue. i have attached link which i have used for comment system in cart page for each product. [image]

Comment: It's difficult to follow your situation. Do you think you could explain a bit more regarding how this started happening?

Comment: I have solved issue. thanks for the asking. ,